# What widget toolkit did RPG Maker XP use?

Tags: user-interface, widget

I want to create something that looks exactly like RPG maker looks wise, does anyone know what widget toolkit they used?

[image: a busy cat]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not ask them? They might even tell.

Comment: Its a Japanese company and I doubt they would tell.

Comment: They build an english developer-oriented software. I'm sure they're interested in talking about technology. Even if you'd be about to directly compete wit them, I doubt they'd win anything by not telling. Because it would not stop you from trying but by telling, they'd ensure you at least wouldn't figure out anything better than they have. And if it's not openly available, who knows you could get your hands on their implementation. Happened to me a couple of times :)